# Add 3rd dimension to a Plane on Blender

Tags: 3d-view, geometry

If you have a plane in the xy axis, but you want it to have a shape (round, heart or anything) on the z axis, how you do that?

[image]

And if you want to rotate a plane or a curve to give it a 3rd dimension on z axis like in the picture (ellipse rotated) below?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`Spin Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/spin.html). For example if you add a Bezier curve, you have to convert the curve to a mesh by doing

`1` Click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Mesh*.
`2` Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to *Edit Mode*
`3` Press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode
`4` Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices
`5` Click the *Spin Tool* in the left toolbox
`6` Select the axis you want to spin around (here X)

In this example my *3D Cursor* is at the World Origin so you have to take its location into consideration we well as the spin function revolves around this cursor.

[image]

Comment: This tool is so much fun! Im happy to know about this, it worked!

Comment: yes its really fun to play with! i remember the first time i used this to create a wine glass. was very easy, just a nice vertically positioned curve and then spin. done! i had a wine glass :)

Answer (score 4):

if you want a non-destructive way doing this, the screw modifier is pretty handy:

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice. thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: This is awesome. In the 360* is a perfect result! Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you!